# Python Flask SQLAlchemy check if database is available

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

before rendering the template I want to check if the database that I am using is available. The database is only available with specific IP, therefore, if someone tries to access the page, I don't want to error everything out, but redirect to a different template without the need for a database.

The error message:

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db-test' (110)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

There is no issue with the error itself, I just want to be able to check if the database is accessible without waiting until the error occurs while loading the page.

storage.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db_req = SQLAlchemy()


class Requests(db_req.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'requests'
    id = db_req.Column(db_req.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    created = db_req.Column(db_req.DateTime, nullable=False)
    name = db_req.Column(db_req.String, nullable=False)
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from models import db_req
from views.requests import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(requests)
app.config.from_object("config.Config")
db_req.init_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

requests.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
from query_request_db import get_fields

requests = Blueprint("requests", __name__)


@requests.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def requests_page():
    # need to check before everything if I can access database not to error out
  return render_template("requests_page.html", names=get_fields.get_field_data("name"))
```

I am trying to find a way to check if the database is available without erroring out. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand you right? that u want to check ip Addresse of the viewer of your Page.

Then u can use

```
request.remote_addr
```

to validate the IP Adress that has access to database ohterwise just do a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Well sort of, I want to see if the viewer can access the database with the IP he has. Since the page is accessible with specific VPN and it has several IP adressess, it would be best to see if the viewer can access the database. For example that sqlalchemy database would return true or false if the connection is possible.